# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add' in Django Models

Tags: python, html, sql, django, visual-studio

I have the next:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'. When I try to add a value to a null field (null=True) with auction.winner.add(u) it gives me that exception. I am working with Django Models and it looks like is not allowed to add a value to a null Field almost with this method. Is there some way to do this?

My models.py:

```py
class Bids(models.Model):
    bid = models.IntegerField(max_length=64)
    user_id2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="user_id2")

class Comments(models.Model):
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=64)
    user_id3 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="user_id3")
    
class Categories(models.Model):
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    
class Auction(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    starting_bid = models.IntegerField(max_length=64)
    photo_url = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="category")
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="user_id")
    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="winner")
    bids = models.ManyToManyField(Bids, blank=True, related_name="bi")
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comments, blank=True, related_name="co")
```

Then my function:

```py
def win(request, auction_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        auction = Auction.objects.get(pk=int(auction_id))
        auction_bids = auction.bids.all()
        j = 0
        for i in auction_bids:
            if i.bid > j:
                j = i.bid
                k = i.user_id2.id
            else:
                pass
        u = User.objects.get(pk=int(k))
        auction.winner.update(u)
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, please can you post the model or models (auction and winner) and also, if it is another model, whatever model `u` represents, I assume that `u` and `winner` relate to the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model that comes with django? You may also need to post any view code or any other model code that relates to your question. Unfortunately, with the original information in this question, it is highly unlikely that you will get a genuinely helpful answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank U, the question is updated and I think it has all the necessary code.

Comment: Good job, and you got your answer too! Sorry I couldnt answer sooner, but indeed Seyed is right :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `winner_id` and then save auction.

```py
def win(request, auction_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        auction = Auction.objects.get(pk=int(auction_id))
        auction_bids = auction.bids.all()
        j = 0
        for i in auction_bids:
            if i.bid > j:
                j = i.bid
                k = i.user_id2.id
            else:
                pass
        auction.winner_id = k
        auction.save(update_fields=["winner"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it’s null and then initialise it to the id of the winner user.

Comment: Yep, it's null. I will try what u say, Thank u and regards.

Comment: Still not working. Is about a ForeignField and it doesn't accept 0 because there is no 0 in the referred field, and it can't be other cause each winner would be the same

Comment: Sorry initialise it with the id of the winner user

Comment: It's not possible because it needs to have default values before updating these with winners id. The way to do that is give a default value of False (null=True) and then if anyone wins, we update the value from False to the winners id. Anyway, Thank u so much!

Comment: *value of None, sorry